# Access not configured displayed when using google custom search api

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

The following script is provided by google api php client

```
<?php
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_CustomsearchService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google CustomSearch PHP Starter Application');
$client->setDeveloperKey('API KEY');
$search = new Google_CustomsearchService($client);

try{
     $result = $search->cse->listCse('burrito', array('cx' => 'SEARCH ENGINE ID'));
     print "<pre>" .print_r($result, true) . "</pre>";
}catch(Exception $e)
{
     echo("<pre>".print_r($e,true)."</pre>");
}
?>
```

When The script is executed the following error is displayed even when `custom search` is enabled in the `services` tab.

```
Google_ServiceException Object
(
    [errors:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [domain] => usageLimits
                    [reason] => accessNotConfigured
                    [message] => Access Not Configured
                )

        )
```

Answer (score 1):

This error could also occur when you try to access an API that you haven't enabled from the API console.

Go to the [API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and enable the API from there first.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/apis/console

register your IPv6 address  not the IPv4

Comment: Can you tell me how to find out IPv6 address? I am using my localhost. Is it 127.0.0.1::1 ?

Comment: Is this correct?
Key for browser apps (with referers)
API key: 00000000
Referers: 
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
Activated on: Jun 25, 2013 11:02 AM
Activated by:  XXX – you

Comment: I hope so, but only you can test it

Comment: at the moment (Jan 2014), it seems only the 'old' ("Google APIs console") interface accepts IPv6 addresses.